# Facebook not allow to use account for ios apps

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have created a IOS app.this app is using login with Facebook its working okay but I have created same copy for code for my new app.I have changed name of the app and also Bundle Identifier and all other setting to compile as a new app.Its not listed under the IOS setting->facebook even Facebook login not working for new app created by same code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the facebook app on [Facebook dev](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) ? You need to do that to get the facebook id to set in your .plist.

See [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) for more information

Comment: Yes I have created a facebook app and also changed app ID in main .plist but still its not working